# Httpi timeout on PUT but POST works

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rest-client, curb, httpi

I am trying to get `PUT` working with `httpi`.  I am using `curb` (`curl`) as my adapter with gss negotiation (I need to use a Kerberos token).  I am able to `GET` the `article_to_update` and I'm able to `POST` new articles using almost the exact same code (remove `article_to_update` from the URL and change `put` to `post`).  With the code below I'm getting 408 errors: "Server timeout waiting for the HTTP request from the client."  I've also tried an empty body and got the same results. 
 Any ideas on how to get this working or to debug further?

Alternate (non-rails) solutions for kerberos-authenticated GET/PUT/POST implementations are welcomed as well.  This is for a REST API but I didn't see if/how the `rest-client` gem supported kerberos.

```
require 'curb'
require 'httpi'
require 'json'

HTTPI.adapter = :curb
url = URI.escape('https://myserver.com/rest/article/article_to_update')
request = HTTPI::Request.new(url: url, open_timeout: 30)
request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
request.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
request.auth.gssnegotiate
request.body = JSON.dump(
    name: 'discovery',
    owner: 'greg'
)
response = HTTPI.put(request)
```

Comment: By any chance it is `Patch`?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon, the API is reporting the following allowed access methods:
`ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, SEARCH, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL`